# How to read dictionary_page values in a parquet file?

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I saw *dictionary_page_offset* and *has_dictionary_page* in the document but couldn't find a way to read the dictionary values.

MY current code not sure is right way.

```py
     for group in range(pq_file.metadata.num_row_groups):
         for col in range(pq_file.metadata.num_columns):
             col_log = {}
             col_meta = pq_file.metadata.row_group(group).column(col)
             dict_page_offset =col_meta.dictionary_page_offset
             print(dict_page_offset)
             dict_page = pq_file.read_row_group(0, columns=[col])
             print(dict_page.to_pylist())
```

Comment: Parquet use dictionary encoding for each column I try to read the  key values in the dictionary page